# how to display different DataTemplate for the message coming from the cloud based on the id?

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, uwp

Hi I am developing a UWP app which is like messenger and I want the user to login then insert the messages in the database. What I need is that: I want to display different DataTemplate for the messages the user send and the messages other users send.
I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br209469(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) to accomplish this. You can follow the steps below:

1. Define your custom DataTemplateSelector class:

   ```
   public class MyTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
   {
       public DataTemplate VIPTemplate { get; set; }//DataTemplate for special user
       public DataTemplate CustomerTemplate { get; set; }//DataTemplate for normal user
       protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
       {
           if (((Customer)item).Id.ToLower() == "vipcustomer")
           {
               //if current user is vip then user VIP Template.
               return VIPTemplate;
           }
           else
           {
               //otherwise return normal template.
               return CustomerTemplate;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add two different templates and the DataTemplateSelector to your page's resources and don't forget to using the namespace first:

   ```
   <Page
        ...
        xmlns:selector="using:DataTemplateSelectorSample.TemplateSelectors"
        ...
   >

   <Page.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="VipTemplate">
          <StackPanel Background="Green" Width="500" Height="25">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate">
          <StackPanel  Width="500" Height="25">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      <selector:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="userTemplateSelector" CustomerTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CustomerTemplate}" VIPTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=VipTemplate}"/>
   </Page.Resources>
   ```
3. Use your custom selector in your ItemsControl:

   ```
   <ListView Name="myListView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource userTemplateSelector}"></ListView>
   ```

Now every user who has the id of `"vipcustomer"` will have a green background.

You can find the complete sample by this link: [DataTemplateSelectorSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/DataTemplateSelectorSample)